# Error when training a neural network with TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm getting the error,

```
DataLossError: truncated record at 20570044
     [[node IteratorGetNext (defined at <ipython-input-6-d6214234a4c0>:16) ]]
```

here is the part of the code that doesn't run :

```
  classifier.train(
    input_fn=lambda: _input_fn([train_path]),
    steps=1000)
```

The same code is running on colab, but not on jupyter lab that got the ssame version of tf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because one of your data files is incomplete. If they are all the same size (or you expect them to be) try sorting by size -- likely you will find one that was improperly downloaded.

The safest fix (if you know the source dataset is uncorrupted) is just to delete and re-download.